# Swith enum can't inherit methods, best way to prevent rewriting same function for every enum

Tags: swift

So I'm writing my networking code using a router design pattern.  I'm writing a new router for different components of my app (should i be doing this? I try to limit my objects lines of code). Heres my router enum. If I was using a class, I could define a method once to populate variables like HTTPMethod and override them if necessary.  Is there a way to do this with enums?  Is it worth implementing or should i repeat the same code.  There are a few other places besides httpMethod such as URL construction where I think this could be helpful. 
I was thinking i could do something with protocols but am not sure if I'm wasting my time.

```
enum PRRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://localhost:8000/"

    case get(Int)
    case create([String : Any])
    case delete(Int)

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        var method: HTTPMethod{
            switch self {
                case .get:
                    return .get
                case .create:
                    return .post
                case.delete:
                    return .delete
            }
        }

    let params : ([String : Any]?) = {
        switch self {
            case .get, .delete:
                return nil
            case .create(let newTodo):
                return newTodo
        }

    }()

    let url : URL = {
        let relativePath: String?
        switch self{
            case .get(let number):
                relativePath =  "test/\(number)"
            case .create:
                relativePath = "test/"
            case .delete:
                relativePath = "test/"

        }
        var url = URL(string: PRRouter.baseURLString)!
        if let relativePath = relativePath {
            url = url.appendingPathComponent(relativePath)
        }
        return url
     }()

     var urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url)
     urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
     let encoding = JSONEncoding.default
     return try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: params)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar in my own project. Here is an example based on your code to get you started:

```
protocol APIProtocol {
    var path: String { get }
    var method: HTTPMethods { get }
    var bodyParameters: [String: Any?]? { get }
}

enum HTTPMethods: String {
    case get = "GET"
    case post = "POST"
}

enum PRRouter: APIProtocol {
    case get(Int)
    case create([String : Any])
    case delete(Int)

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case let .get(number):
            return "test/\(number)"
        default:
            return "test"
        }
    }

    var method: HTTPMethods {
        return .get
    }

    var bodyParameters: [String : Any?]? {
        return nil
    }
}

extension APIProtocol {
    func execute(completion: @escaping ((Data?) -> Void)) -> URLSessionDataTask? {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/\(path)") else { return nil }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        if let bodyParameters = bodyParameters {
            urlRequest.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyParameters, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
            completion(data)
        }
        task.resume()
        return task
    }
}
```

Finally you can use it like this:

```
let dataTask = PRRouter.get(2).execute { (data) in
    //
}
```

You could extend this further by changing the completion block in the execute function to return a deserialized object.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Make the enum conform to a protocol with a default implementation.

```
protocol P {
    func f()
}

extension P {
    func f() { print("default implementation") }
}

enum E: P {
    case Foo
}

let e = E.Foo

e.f()
```